# Compiling a sample SDL2 program with gcc/cygwin on windows: undefined reference to WinMain

Tags: c, gcc, compiler-errors, cygwin, sdl-2

I browsed the whole internet and tried every solution for this, without result.

What I'm using:

- Windows 10
- Cygwin
- gcc compiler

I'm trying to compile this simple code:

```
#include "SDL.h"

int main(int ac, char **av)
{
    return 0;
}
```

This is what my makefile looks like:

```
hellosdl:
    gcc hellosdl.c -L../SDL2-2.0.18/x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib -lSDL2main -lSDL2 -mwindows -I../SDL2-2.0.18/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/SDL2
```

where `-lSDL2main -lSDL2 -mwindows` is the output of `sdl2-config --libs`, minus -lmingw32.

Output:

```
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/10/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/10/../../../../lib/libcygwin.a(libcmain.o): in function `main':
/usr/src/debug/cygwin-3.2.0-1/winsup/cygwin/lib/libcmain.c:37: undefined reference to `WinMain'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [Makefile:3: hellosdl] Error 1
```

What am I not understanding?

Comment: Judgning by error message I suspect you need to link with `cygwin` instead of `mingw32`, so it should be, in that order: `-lcygwin -lSDL2main -lSDL2`.

Comment: Thank you! It compiles now, even though it doesn't run: `error while loading shared libraries: SDL2.dll: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

Comment: As usual with windows, you need to put `SDL2.dll` to the same directory where your `exe` resides, or drop it to system directory (probably not recommended, but could be useful for development).

Comment: Is `x86_64-pc-cygwin` Cygwin even compatible with `x86_64-w64-mingw32` prebuilt SDL2? I wouldn't expect it to be. Do you really need Cygwin, maybe MSYS2 would suffice?

Comment: Thank you very much for your comments, it works now! I will also look into MSYS2.